# Can't create AdCreative using facebook-nodejs-business-sdk module in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook-graph-api, facebook-node-sdk

I am trying upload image using `facebook-nodejs-business-sdk`. I am getting error which is given below:

```
{ error:
      { message: 'Invalid parameter',
        type: 'OAuthException',
        code: 100,
        error_subcode: 1443186,
        is_transient: false,
        error_user_title: 'Image couldn\'t be loaded',
        error_user_msg:
         'There was a problem while loading your image. Please try uploading the image again or choose a different image.',
        fbtrace_id: 'A7_XjnvwsvVzYb0cnCZUXdi' } },
  method: 'POST',
  url:
   'https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/act_578276446245361/adcreatives?access_token=<access_token_provided>,
data:
   { name: 'Sample Image Upload',
     object_story_spec: { page_id: '<page_id>', link_data: {image_hash:<image_hash>,link:'<page_link>','message':'Ad message'} },
     id: 'act_<account_id>' } }
```

I have tried all the images such as .jpg, .png, .bmp, .git. Nothing worked. Any help would be helpful. Thanks. for further doubt or any question comment me or messag me. Thanks.